# Finding closest latitude and longitude and Z value from data frame

Tags: r

I have data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(long = c( 50.75  80.75   0.75  65.75  70.75  75.75 100.75 105.75 110.75         
                  -4.25  65.75,100.55), lat=c(13.3 13.8 13.8 13.8 13.8 13.8 13.8 13.8 13.8 
                   13.8 13.8,14.8), XCh4 c(1739.9 1737.5 1740.5 1715.7 1728.5 1745.0 1724.6
                   1734.2 1733.4 1713.6 1716.3 1725.3))
```

and I have station value which is

```
lon<- 100.60

lat <-13.4
```

So how I should extract closest latitude and longitude to station and also get the z value?
I have tried:

```
lat.match   <- which(abs(data[[3]]$lat - 13.04) == min(abs(data[[3]]$lat - 14.04)))[1]

lon.match   <- which(abs(data$long - 100.60)== min(abs(data$long- 100.60)))[1]

data[data$long[lon.match] & data$lat[lat.match],]
```

I do not get the exact pair of latitude longitude which suppose to be lat = 13.8 and longitude = 100.75.

Could somebody please tell me how I can get my answer?

Comment: z here is XCh4 it was typo mistake in question

Comment: Do you want to find the station that is really the nearest, geographically speaking, or the one with the least difference between the value of latitude and longitude coordinates? It may affect your answer if you have more data that covers a greater spatial extent

Comment: If either of the solutions posted below works for you can you please accept one by pressing the green tick next to the answer you prefer so that the question can be taken off the unanswered questions stack. If they don't work can you give us more information so we can better assist? I see you have posted questions, but never accepted an answer (you can even accept your own answer and gain points!) or voted to say a solution is useful or not.

Comment: You haven't accepted any of the 4 answers given below.  If the answers didn't serve the purpose you may seek further clarification, but if these di serve your purpose, you should accept one answer closest to your expectation.  IT not only helps the answerer to gain some reputation/votes, as a token of gratitude,  but also helps in future reference.  That serves the basic purpose of Stack Overflow.  I hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

Editing to acknowledge that the longitude differences are reduced by the latitude-shrinkage and the fact that the code was calculating not a "distance" but "degrees squared":

```
data$degr.sqrd <- ( (lon-data$long)*cos(90*data$lat ) )^2 + (lat-data$lat)^2
 which.min(data$degr.sqrd)
#[1] 7
data[ which.min(data$degr.sqrd), "XCh4"]
#[1] 1724.6

data[ which.min(data$degr.sqrd), ]
#    long  lat   XCh4 degr.sqrd
#7 100.75 13.8 1724.6 0.1651696
```

Comment: The OP has geographic coordinates, this kind of distance calculation assumes planar (or projected) coordinates.

Comment: Excellent point, although I think simply introducing a cos(90*lat) adjustment would be a highly accurate approximation in this case. After all the request was not for hte distance but rather to select a particular record.

Comment: True, but he does want to select the record based on closest distance. I feel that means that a 'true' distance calculation is also therefore an important and relevant part of the answer?

Comment: We apparently disagree about what approximation is needed and whether a distance was actually requested. I had intentionally not calculated a distance and I should not have labeled it "dist". We do not disagree about the desirability of making an adjustment and I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: I see what you mean... does "*how I should extract closest latitude and longitude to station*" mean he wants the nearest lat/long or does he mean the nearest *geographically speaking*? I took it to mean the latter, but it could just as easily have been the former. In which case I +1 you

Comment: I just need to find nearest lat/long in existing database, the existing database is already grided on 0.5 x 0.5.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful! You have lat-long coordinates. Don't use methods that assume coordinates are planar, that is a unit of measurement is the same in the vertical and horizontal directions, which is not the case with geographic coordinates. In the example data it does not make a difference, but it might do if you have lots of data across larger scales. Instead you should look to calculate great circle distances (or some derivative of this). Try this instead:

```
r <- 6371 # radius of the Earth
#Coordinates need to be in radians
data$longR <- data$long * pi/180
data$latR <- data$lat * pi/180
lon <- 100.60 * pi/180
lat <- 13.4 * pi/180
data$dist <- acos(sin( lat ) * sin( data$latR ) + cos( lat ) * cos( data$latR) * cos( data$longR -lon ) ) * r
data[ which.min( data$dist ) , ]
    long  lat   XCh4    longR      latR    dist
7 100.75 13.8 1724.6 1.758419 0.2408554 47.3403
```

The distance metric is in the same scale as the radius of the earth (so 47.3 km in this case). There's a great blog post on different distance calculation methods [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/great-circle-distance-calculations-in-r/)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `dist` ,

```
mat <- dist(cbind(c(data$lat,lat),c(data$long,lon)))
n <- attr(mat,'Size')
i <- 1:n
j <- n
v <- mat[n*(i-1) - i*(i-1)/2 + j-i]
data[which.min(v),]
long  lat   XCh4   dist
7 100.75 13.8 1724.6 0.1825
```

The advantage here , you can change the distance for example, for example:

```
mat <- dist(cbind(c(data$lat,lat),c(data$long,lon)),meath='minkowski')

data[which.min(v),]
    long  lat   XCh4   dist
7 100.75 13.8 1724.6 0.1825  ## not really representative , we get the same result:)
```